# jquery dynamic css selector Case Insensitive

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, jquery-selectors

I am looking for a way to dynamicly see if a img has an alt tag containing the string entered by the user everything is working but i would like to make it case insensitive for usability

my php

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-heading"><span><?php echo $heading_title; ?></span> <input type="text"     id="refine" placeholder="refine"></div>
<div class="box-content">
<div class="box-category">
  <ul class="manufacturers">
    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
    <li class="manufacturer" >
        <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $manufacturer['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?>" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
<script>
$("#refine").keyup(function() {
var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
if(filter) {
    $matches = $('.manufacturer a img[alt*=' + filter + '] ');
    console.log($matches);
    $('.manufacturer a img').not($matches).slideUp();
    $matches.slideDown();
} else {
     $('.manufacturer a img').slideDown();
    }
    return false;

});
 </script>
```

I would like to preserve the manufacturers name capitalisation in the markup.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have built-in case-insensitive selectors. You'll have to write a function that does the comparison and use `.filter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To both preserve the capitalisation in the `alt` attribute and get it to work, you could provide a lower case variant in another attribute like so:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-heading"><span><?php echo $heading_title; ?></span> <input type="text"     id="refine" placeholder="refine"></div>
<div class="box-content">
<div class="box-category">
  <ul class="manufacturers">
    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
    <li class="manufacturer" >
        <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $manufacturer['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?>" data-filter="<?php echo strtolower($manufacturer['name']); ?>" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the Javascript

```
<script>
$("#refine").keyup(function() {
var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
if(filter) {
    $matches = $('.manufacturer a img[data-filter*=' + filter + '] ');
    console.log($matches);
    $('.manufacturer a img').not($matches).slideUp();
    $matches.slideDown();
} else {
     $('.manufacturer a img').slideDown();
    }
    return false;

});
 </script>
```